# wsimport is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: web-services, soap, jaxb, apache-axis, axis

I am trying to generate the files using wsimport and i am getting the above error. I have done the following steps:

**1)** JAVA_HOME -set to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
**2)** c:\Desktop\Temp>wsimport http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL -extension -keep 
running the above command results in error.

I have also tried appending /bin to the JAVA_HOME but it does not remove the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a JDK, not JRE. XJC is not a part of JRE `bin`.

`JAVA_HOME` variable does not include bin:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_29
```

However `PATH` should include `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: Hey I am attempting a similar thing and am getting errors as well; can you check out my question @lexicore  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555188/unable-to-run-wsimport-utility-in-jdk8

Answer (score 0):

This is where my jdk is, works for my system:

Go to My computer >> right click and select properties.
On the properties tab select Advanced system settings (Windows 7)
Click enviroment variables
select path and click edit option
add
";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin"
at the end.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem:

If you are 100% sure that everything is set-up.Try to close cmd and reopen it. It should start recognizing it.